# How to use gethostbyname_r in MAC OS

Tags: c++, macos

I have a written a network utility. I am using function `gethostbyname_r`. This function compiles well on Linux environment, but when I try to compile the same code on MAC OS, I am getting the following error:

> ‘gethostbyname_r’ was not declared in this scope

Is there any other function or counterpart that I can use on MAC?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should use `getaddrinfo` instead of `gethostbyname`. While many platforms have a `gethostbyname` function, it is inconsistent in its properties, such as whether it is thread-safe; it also provides no means for the caller to specify whether they would prefer IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. `getaddrinfo` was introduced as a standardised function without these deficiencies.

That said, the equivalent to `gethostbyname_r` on macOS, is actually just `gethostbyname`. On some platforms, such as Linux, `gethostbyname` was implemented in a non-threadsafe way (returning its result in a static buffer shared by all threads); rather than changing the implementation to be thread-safe (such as by allocating that buffer in thread-local memory), `gethostbyname_r` was introduced to use a caller-supplied buffer instead. However, on macOS, `gethostbyname` was already thread-safe, so introduction of a separate thread-safe `gethostbyname_r` was seen as unnecessary.

You could actually implement your own `gethostbyname_r` function, based on `gethostbyname`. However, it would be more worthwhile to spend that effort changing your code to use `getaddrinfo` instead.

In addition to macOS, other platforms on which `gethostbyname` is thread-safe (and hence `gethostbyname_r` is unnecessary) include FreeBSD, Windows, AIX (4.3+), HP-UX (11+), and z/OS UNIX. Note that AIX actually has a `gethostbyname_r` function, even though that is strictly unnecessary given its `gethostbyname` is thread-safe; macOS, FreeBSD, Windows and z/OS UNIX don't.

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the Linux [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname_r) you will see that `gethostbyname_r` is listed under "GNU extensions". This means that it's not available on non-GNU platforms (like OSX).